# Attribute 'DisplayColumn' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class' declarations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Just wondering why I get compile time error :

> "Attribute 'DisplayColumn' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class' declarations."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApplication.Models.DataAnnotations
{

    [MetadataType(typeof(AppUser_DataAnnotations))]
    public partial class AppUser
    {

    }

    public class AppUser_DataAnnotations
    {
        [DisplayColumn("Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm using above to override mvccontrib rendered grid column headers. Any idea why I get compile time error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting a compile-time error is because the [`[DisplayColumn]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displaycolumnattribute.aspx) attribute can only be applied at the class level and not at a property of the class. You are probably confusing this attribute with [`[DisplayName]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx).

Comment: Ohhh my bad. Good catch thanks ! But I do not find [DisplayName] anywhere. Am I missing some namespace? Thanks.

Comment: Found it... using System.ComponentModel; is what was missing. Still, I don't get the header overriden.

Answer (score 4):

For people who run into this problem in the future maybe this can help:

I got the same problem as described above. As described in other answers it is important to use the DisplayName property and to include the System.ComponentModel namespace. Besides that, the property must have a getter (and setter) to get the attribute working. The errormessage is a bit confusing on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run into this problem when you decorate a **Model Property** with the attribute.

You need to decorate **Controller Method's** with `ActionFilterAttribute`'s *not property's*.